# LSTM: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I know there are several questions about this here, but I haven't found one which fits exactly my problem.
I'm trying to fit an LSTM with data from Pandas DataFrames but getting confused about the format I have to provide them.
I created a small code snipped which shall show you what I try to do:

```
import pandas as pd, tensorflow as tf, random
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

targets = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', periods=300, freq='D'))
targets['A'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(targets))]
targets['B'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(targets))] 
features = pd.DataFrame(index=targets.index)
for i in range(len(features)) :
    features[str(i)] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(features))] 

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=targets.shape[1], input_shape=features.shape))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')

model.fit(features, targets, batch_size=10, epochs=10)
```

this results to:

*ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [10, 300]*

which I expect relates to the dimensions of the **features** DataFrame provided. I guess that  once fixed this the next error would mention the **targets** DataFrame.

As far as I understand, 'units' parameter of my first layer defines the output dimensionality of this model. The inputs have to have a 3D shape, but I don't know how to create them out of the 2D world of the Data Frames.
I hope you can help me understanding the reshape mechanism in Python and how to use them in combination with Pandas DataFrames. (I'm quite new to Python and came from R)

Thankls in advance

Comment: what is the shape of your features?

Comment: targets : (300, 2)
features : (300, 300)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets looks at the few popular ways in [LSTMs](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) are used.

## Many to Many

Example: You have a sentence (composed of words in sequence). Give these sequence of words you would like to predict the Parts of speech (POS) of each word.

[image]

So you have `n` words and you feed each word per timestep to the LSTM. Each LSTM timestep (also called LSTM unwrapping) will produce and output. The word is represented by a a set of features normally word embeddings. So the input to LSTM is of size `bath_size X time_steps X features`

### Keras code:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,3))
lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(8, input_shape = (10, 3), return_sequences = True)(inputs)
outputs = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))(lstm)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

X = np.random.randn(4,10,3) 
y = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(4,10,5))

model.fit(X, y, epochs=2)
print (model.predict(X).shape)
```

## Many to One

Example: Again you have a sentence (composed of words in sequence). Give these sequence of words you would like to predict sentiment of the sentence if it is positive or negative.

[image]

### Keras code

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,3))
lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(8, input_shape = (10, 3), return_sequences = False)(inputs)
outputs =keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(lstm)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

X = np.random.randn(4,10,3) 
y = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(4,5))

model.fit(X, y, epochs=2)
print (model.predict(X).shape)
```

## Many to multi-headed

Example: You have a sentence (composed of words in sequence). Give these sequence of words you would like to predict sentiment of the sentence as well the author of the sentence.

This is multi-headed model where one head will predict the sentiment and another head will predict the author. Both the heads share the same LSTM backbone.

[image]

### Keras code

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,3))
lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(8, input_shape = (10, 3), return_sequences = False)(inputs)
output_A = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(lstm)
output_B = keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(lstm)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output_A, output_B])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

X = np.random.randn(4,10,3) 
y_A = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(4,5))
y_B = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(4,5))

model.fit(X, [y_A, y_B], epochs=2)
y_hat_A, y_hat_B = model.predict(X)
print (y_hat_A.shape, y_hat_B.shape)
```

What you are looking for is Many to Multi head model where your predictions for `A` will be made by one head and another head will make predictions for `B`

Comment: thanks mujjiga for the detailed explanation, I will need some time to digest ;)

Answer (score 0):

The input data for the LSTM has to be 3D.

If you print the shapes of your DataFrames you get:

```py
targets : (300, 2)
features : (300, 300)
```

The input data has to be reshaped into `(samples, time steps, features)`. This means that *targets* and *features* must have the same shape.

You need to set a number of *time steps* for your problem, in other words, how many samples will be used to  make a prediction.

For example, if you have 300 days and 2 features the *time step* can be 3. So that three days will be used to make one prediction (you can choose this arbitrarily). Here is the code for reshaping your data (with a few more changes):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

data = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', periods=300, freq='D'))
data['A'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(data))]
data['B'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(data))]

# Choose the time_step size.
time_steps = 3
# Use numpy for the 3D array as it is easier to handle.
data = np.array(data)

def make_x_y(ts, data):
    """
    Parameters
    ts : int
    data : numpy array

    This function creates two arrays, x and y. 
    x is the input data and y is the target data.
    """
    x, y = [], []
    offset = 0
    for i in data:
        if offset < len(data)-ts:
            x.append(data[offset:ts+offset])
            y.append(data[ts+offset])
            offset += 1
    return np.array(x), np.array(y)

x, y = make_x_y(time_steps, data)

print(x.shape, y.shape)

nodes = 100  # This is the width of the network.
out_size = 2  # Number of outputs produced by the network. Same size as features.

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=nodes, input_shape=(x.shape[1], x.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(out_size))  # For the output a Dense (fully connected) layer is used.
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=10, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus,

what if I need a multivariate target LSTM model?
I'll try to update my original post to be more concrete

Comment: @WasiliosGoutas the model is already multivariate as you created the `A` and `B` columns. The number of variables is determined by the *features*. In this example the data has shape (297, 3, 2), 297 *samples*, 3 *time steps* and 2 *features* (variables). The output must be the same size as the features. (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: LSTM is not realy clear to me.
In my view *y* is what I'm going to predict with the model I'm training with *x*
But if *x* and *y* must have the same shape, it seems it will not be possible to do that.
In my example I would like to predict the columns *['A', 'B']* by training a model with 100 features ['0' ... '99'].
Is this not possible with LSTM?

Comment: @WasiliosGoutas each column will have 100 time steps. You split the data in `x` and `y` so that the model learns to produce `y` if it sees an `x`. Instead of training on the whole sample you train on small parts of it iteratively.

Comment: does it mean, that LTSM is not using x to predict y but will use x+y to predict x+y (predict always the complete _row_ of a dataset)?
I'm sorry, but so far I only used sklearn shallow models. Maybe this is why I don't understand the NN world as I should

Comment: @WasiliosGoutas based on your suggested edit it seems that your data has 100 *features* (columns). How exactly does your data looks like (rows and columns, etc)? What are you trying to predict? As for your last comment, the LSTM maps the sequence `x` to `y` so yes, the output will be the next row in the sequence.

Comment: sorry for the late response.
I think I understand now how the input needs to be processed. It seems a generator is been needed which provides the data in a form of a sliding window over the raw data... I will try to implement it the way I think and once it works I will provide my solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to finalize this issue I would like to provide one solution I have meanwhile worked on. The class TimeseriesGenerator in tf.keras.... enabled me quite easy to provide the data in the right shape to an LSTM model

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import numpy as np

window_size   = 7
batch_size    = 8
sampling_rate = 1

train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X_train.values, y_train.values,
                               length=window_size, sampling_rate=sampling_rate,
                               batch_size=batch_size)

valid_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X_valid.values, y_valid.values,
                               length=window_size, sampling_rate=sampling_rate,
                               batch_size=batch_size)
test_gen  = TimeseriesGenerator(X_test.values, y_test.values,
                               length=window_size, sampling_rate=sampling_rate,
                               batch_size=batch_size)
```

There are many other ways on implementing generators e.g. using the more_itertools which provides the function *windowed*, or making use of tensorflow.Dataset and its function *window*.
For me the *TimeseriesGenerator* was sufficient to feed the tests I did.
In case you would like to see an example modeling the DAX based on some stocks I'm  sharing a [notebook](https://gist.github.com/laiki/8a81bb01e6cd96d54ad1d101d20fb3b6#file-rnn_tests-ipynb) on Github.